# Proof on Cauchy Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Basically, Rudin states that a Cauchy sequence in a compact metric space is convergent. However, his proof is a bit non-intuitive and different from what one comprehends at first sight.

Thus, I have put my own proof, but I want it to be checked if correct, since it seems to be way more intuitive.

If $p_n$ takes only a finite number of values but is not ultimately constant, then it is obvious that cannot be Cauchy. Thus, a Cauchy sequence has an infinite number of values.

Thus, a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence $p_{n_k}$ that converges to $p$. Thus, there is $N_1$ such that $d(p_{N_1},p)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

However, since it's a Cauchy sequence, $d(p_n,p_m)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\forall n,m>N_2$  for some $N_2<N_1$. (To obtain that, we choose a large enough $N_1$)

Thus, $\forall n>N_2$, $d(p_n,p)\leq d(p_n,p_{N_1})+d(p_{N_1},p)<\varepsilon$.

QED.

Comment: Why can't a Cauchy sequence take a finite number of values?

Comment: $\{p_n\}$ with $p_n=0$ for all $n$ is obviously Cauchy and takes only finitely many values.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a Cauchy sequence that is not ultimately constant.

Comment: Why should a Cauchy sequence have a convergent subsequence? The space being compact is not being used anywhere.

Comment: That is exactly where it's being used. Since I said that it has an infinite number of values, and since the space is compact, then it must have a convergent subsequence. Is that not true?

Comment: Yes, but this uses the fact that compactness implies limit point compactness, and that requires a proof imo.

Comment: That is already proved in Rudin. He already proved that every sequence on a compact space has a convergent subsequence, so I freely used that fact.

Comment: This proof looks fine then.

Comment: @catfish Yeah, my previous statement is not entirely precise. We need to show that compactness implies sequential compactness in a metric space (not limit point compactness as I wrote earlier).

Comment: It doesn't matter since I got what you meant. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence $p_{n_k}$ that converges to $p$" uses the result that every sequence in a compact metric space has a convergent subsequence. If you proved this earlier, the proof looks fine.